# eigenvalue clustering igraph

Tags: igraph, social-networking, eigen, hierarchical-clustering

When using the cluster_leading_eigen function in R iGraph package I'm not able to merge the communities into two communities. The following gives a warning:

```
karate <- make_graph("Zachary")
wc <- cluster_edge_betweenness(karate)
cut_at(wc, no=2)
```

I can see that the merges matrix has a different structure than from the one I get from e.g. cluster_edge_betweenness; but I don't understand why.